# Heroku failed to install production dependencies with NPM

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I do a build at Heroku, for my node.js app, It replies back with the following messages.

[image]

It says **`Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app`**
However, I have pushed all dependencies in code itself. Why is the build failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build is failing because *node-waf* isn't in your path. You can check if you have the path configured properly by running `which node-waf`.

*node-waf* has actually been [superseded](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/ChangeLog#L1081) by *node-gyp*, but you can still install it. It goes under the name `nodejs-dev` on some package managers.

You might also already have the package on your system. I suggest looking in `/usr/local/bin`. If the binary is there, then you can add a system shortcut for access.

Comment: Yup. That was the  case !

Answer (score 0):

Please post your package.json. You are including some very old packages, that require node-waf instead of node-gyp. If you remove the version numbers from those packages, it will probably work.